# Need Javascript syntax help returning array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to return the following array of objects:

```
{
    "2013-04-30": {"number": 5, "url": "www.yahoo.com"},
    "2013-05-04": {"number": 18, "url": "www.google.com"}
}
```

I'm having trouble getting the syntax correct I've tried the following few ways without success. My code:

```
var returnEvents = [];
$.each(events, function (index, item) {       

//returnEvents.push(item.Date, { 'number': item.Number, 'url': item.URL });

//returnEvents.push({ id: item.Date, value: { 'number': item.Number, 'url': item.URL } });

//var temp = {};
//temp[item.Date] = { 'number': item.Number, 'url': item.URL };
//returnEvents.push(temp);           

});
```

Comment: That's not an array of objects. It's an object that contains objects as values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final result is an object, not an array. You need to assign to it using `[]` syntax to specify the property names dynamically.

```js
var events = [
  { Date: "2013-04-30",
    Number: 5,
    URL: "www.yahoo.com"
  },
  { Date: "2013-05-04",
    Number: 18,
    URL: "www.google.com"
  }
];

var returnEvents = {};
$.each(events, function (index, item) {       
 returnEvents[item.Date] = { 'number': item.Number, 'url': item.URL };
});
                 
console.log(returnEvents);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is object, not array. So you should not use `push`. Just try below:

```
var returnEvents = {};
$.each(events, function (index, item) { 
    returnEvents[item.Date] = { 'number': item.Number, 'url': item.URL };
});
```

If you need the **return as array**, your expected return data should be defined as :

```
[
    {"2013-04-30": {"number": 5, "url": "www.yahoo.com"}},
    {"2013-05-04": {"number": 18, "url": "www.google.com"}}
]
```

Then you can build this data as below:

```
var returnEvents = [];
$.each(events, function (index, item) { 
    returnEvents.push({item.Date :{ 'number': item.Number, 'url': item.URL }});
});
```